# Symfony query builder get value without keys

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I have a problem getting the result I want.
I always get the key together with the value but I just want to get the value.

I have some code like this:

```
$qb
  ->select('a.id')
  ->from(Article::class, 'a')
  ...
  ->getQuery()
  ->getArrayResult();
```

and my result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 111 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 222 ) 
)
```

but I want it to be like:

```
Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 222 )
```

I have tried to user ->getResult(), ->getArrayResult() and stuff like that but I never came to the right solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are being returned an array or ResultSet rows, you will always be passed an array of rows. What else could be returned! So if you want the array you say, you will have to manipulate it after it is returned from the query

Comment: Mhm yes okay. I know that I can manipulate it later but I was hoping that there is another solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getSingleColumnResult()` gets you a one dimensional array.